# Iphone app development - How do I reload(?) views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, viewdidload

Okay, I'm working on a iPhone game.  You start off on a menu screen, then select "New Game" or "High Scores".  Let's select "New Game."

The first time you do this, you get an alert telling you how to play the game.  I implemented this with the - (id)initWithNibName function.  Here is the exact code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {

//Alert Here

}
return self;
```

}

It works great.  However, if I go back to the main menu, then return to the game screen, this alert does not pop up (it only pops up the first time the user clicks "New Game").

I am also using an viewDidLoad function, just as a side note.

Here is the code I am using to implement my nib (I believe):

```
        [mainViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [introViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [introView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];
    [self.view insertSubview:menuButton aboveSubview:mainViewController.view];
    [introViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [mainViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Once again,
Many Thanks

Comment: please show the code you're using to load the nib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the `- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method to display the alert view. This will get called every time a view controller's view is added to a window.

[Here's the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17)